# Google Maps v3 parse through all markers to get the latitude and longitude of each

Tags: google-maps-api-3

All my markers are placed in the array "markersArray[]". I want to parse through them and retrieve their current individual latitude and longitude so I can add them to a string I then pass to PHP. Here are all the ways I've tried with no luck (getting latitude only for testing purposes).

```
function test() {
alert("markersArray.length " + markersArray.length) 
    for( var i = 0, n = markersArray.length; i < n; ++i ) {
        var markerLat = parseFloat(markersArray[i].getAttribute("lng")) 
        //var markerLat = map.markersArray[i].getPoint().lat();
        //var markerLat = map.markersArray[i].getPoint().lat();
        //var markerLat = map.markersArray[i].latLng.lat().toFixed(3);
        //var markerLat = map.markersArray[i].position.lat();
        alert("markerLat " + markerLat)             
    }
}
```

I have no problem getting other attributes of the markers, I don't understand why this should be so difficult. :(

Comment: `map.markersArray[i]` is wrong, it should just be `markersArray[i]`.  There is no `getAttribute` on the marker or MVCObject classes. As @geocodezip says, you can use `getPosition()`, and then you can use `getPosition().lat()` / `getPosition().lng()` if you need the individual latitude and/or longitude values.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, getPosition()lng() works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why guess? The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) says `google.maps.Marker.getPosition()` (assuming your markersArray contains google.maps.Marker objects, you don't provide the code that initializes it).